# Find two densities' point of intersection in R

Tags: r

I have two densities that overlap as seen in the attached picture. I want to find out where the two lines meet. How would I go about doing that?

[image: Density Plot]

This is the code that produced the image:

```
... #reading in files etc.
pdf("test-plot.pdf")
d1 <- density(somedata) 

d2 <- density(someotherdata)

plot(d1)

par(col="red")
lines(d2)

dev.off()
```

The original data is just two monodimensional vectors, so what I'm interested in is the intersection point of their densities.

I tried to use the solution shown in [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/intersection-of-2-density-curves-td891865.html), but unfortunately, it neither gives me a number nor even draws the lines correctly:

[image: Doesn't work for me]

**edit:** [I have found what I was looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21213177/1016216)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure your answers are correct, but here's what finally worked for me:

```
d1$x[abs(d1$y-d2$y) < 0.00001 && d1$x < 1000 && d1$x > 500]
```

(because I really only needed to find out one value and am a total R newbie, which made it difficult to understand your answers, since I don't even understand most basic R concepts yet. Thank you for your help and sorry.

Answer (score 3):

```
# create and plot example data
set.seed(1)
plotrange <- c(-1,8)
d1 <- density(rchisq(1000, df=2), from=plotrange[1], to=plotrange[2])
d2 <- density(rchisq(1000, df=3)-1, from=plotrange[1], to=plotrange[2])
plot(d1)
lines(d2)

# look for points of intersection
poi <- which(diff(d1$y > d2$y) != 0) 

# Mark those points with a circle:
points(x=d1$x[poi], y=d1$y[poi], col="red")

# or with lines:
abline(v=d1$x[poi], col="orange", lty=2)
abline(h=d1$y[poi], col="orange", lty=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

`intersect(x,y)`

see this [help file](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html)

For example: If your data are in the same data.frame `df`

`intersect(df$col1, df$col2)`

Comment: I don't quite understand how to use that. If I call it on my two densities, it doesn't add anything to the plot and its output doesn't contain any numbers..

Comment: The data is just two text file with a number per line that are read into `somedata` and `someotherdata`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small example extending John's answer with an example.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(x = round(rnorm(100, 20, 10),1), y = round((100/log(100:199)),1))
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 200 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ variable: Factor w/ 2 levels "x","y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ value   : num  16.8 25.7 20.5 22 19 ...

# Melt and plot
mdf <- melt(df)
ggplot(mdf) +
  geom_density(aes(x = value, color = variable))
```

[image]

```
# Find points that intersect  
intersect(df$x, df$y)
# [1] 18.9 20.1 21.3 21.5 21.0 19.6 19.0 20.0 19.8

# To make the answer more complete, here is the source code of intersect.
function (x, y) 
{
    y <- as.vector(y)
    unique(y[match(as.vector(x), y, 0L)])
}
<bytecode: 0x10285d400>
<environment: namespace:base>
> 

# It's actually posible to use unique and match to produce the same output
unique(as.vector(df$y)[match(as.vector(df$x), df$y, 0L)])
# [1] 18.9 20.1 21.3 21.5 21.0 19.6 19.0 20.0 19.8!
```